# getDescription not working

Tags: c#, oop

Why in beverage2.getDescription() is Unkown Beverage and beverage3.getDescription() is House Blend Coffe,

but beverage2.cost(), and beverage3.cost() is 1,09

Why polymorphism not working?
I mean why beverage2.getDescription() not called "return this.beverage.getDescription() + ", Mocha";"

I want to get:
beverage2.getDescription() the same result like beverage3.getDescription()

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Beverage beverage2 = new HouseBlend();
        beverage2 = new Mocha(beverage2);
        Console.WriteLine(beverage2.getDescription() + " $" + beverage2.cost());


        var beverage3 = new Mocha(new HouseBlend());
        Console.WriteLine(beverage3.getDescription() + " $" + beverage3.cost());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public abstract class Beverage
{
    public string description = "Unkown Beverage";

    public string getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public abstract double cost();
}

public abstract class CondomenentDecorator : Beverage
{
    public abstract string getDescription();
}



public class HouseBlend : Beverage
{
    public HouseBlend()
    {
        description = "House Blend Coffe"; 
    }

    public override double cost()
    {
        return .89;
    }
}

public class Mocha : CondomenentDecorator
{
    Beverage beverage;

    public Mocha(Beverage beverage)
    {
        this.beverage = beverage;
        this.beverage.description = beverage.description;
    }

    public override string getDescription()
    {
        return this.beverage.getDescription() + ", Mocha";
    }

    public override double cost()
    {
        return .20 + beverage.cost();
    }
}
```

Comment: Polymorphism *is* working, but you got your class hierarchy somewhat backwards. You should have the abstract getDescription in the base class, instead of (re)introducing it further down the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Because the compiler warns you:

> 'CondomenentDecorator.getDescription()' hides inherited member 'Beverage.getDescription()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

So you are not overriding that method. Hence, if it gets called from the base class, it returns the value from the base class.

You should not define an `abstract` method in `CondomenentDecorator` since it is already derived from `Beverage`.

Also, to be able to override the `getDescription` from `Beverage`, the `getDescription` should be defined `virtual`:

```
public virtual string getDescription() { }
```